# What is the time format used in facebook created date?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, datetime

Hi i am working on facebook Graph API where i need all the posts information of a group. So I did it and saw `[created_date'] => '2013-01-25T00:11:02+0000'` what does this date and time represent i mean i know  `2013-01-25` is date and `00:11:02` is time but what does `T` and `+0000` represent.

BTW where is the server of facebook. Which timestamp should i use to match facebook time?

Thank you.

Comment: It's [`ISO 8601`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to be precise

Answer (score 29, accepted):

T = TIME and the +0000 is timezone offset.  Facebook uses localized timezones.  You can request a Unix timestamp instead of the string by adding the parameter: date_format=U to your graph API call.

Please see [this link](https://chris.banes.me/2011/06/24/correctly-parsing-graph-api-event-times/) for more information.

Comment: @HighParkCoder what does localized timezone means?

Answer (score 13):

The date format is called [`ISO 8601`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The letter `T` is used to separate date and time unambiguously and `+0000` is used to signify the timezone offset, in this case GMT or UTC.

That said, you generally don't need to worry so much about the actual contents; rather you should know how to work with them. To use such a date, you can use `strtotime()` to convert it into a time-stamp:

```
$ts = strtotime('2013-01-25T00:11:02+0000');
```

To convert the time-stamp back into a string representation, you can simply use `gmdate()` with the predefined date constant [`DATE_ISO8601`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601):

```
echo gmdate(DATE_ISO8601, $ts);
```

Alternatively, using [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
// import date
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2013-01-25T00:11:02+0000');

// export date
echo $dd->format(DateTime::ISO8601), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: *sidenote:* `DateTime::createFromFormat()` is available since 5.3.0

Answer (score 5):

This is a standard format, specifically [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

As much as I don't like linking to it, http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp does have a good "human-understandable" explanation:

> The dateTime is specified in the following form "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"
>   where:
>
> ```
> YYYY indicates the year
> MM indicates the month
> DD indicates the day
> T indicates the start of the required time section
> hh indicates the hour
> mm indicates the minute
> ss indicates the second
> ```
>
> To specify a time zone, you can either enter a dateTime in UTC time by
>   adding a "Z" behind the time - like this:
>
> `2002-05-30T09:30:10Z`
>
> or you can specify an offset from the UTC time by adding a positive or
>   negative time behind the time - like this:
>
> `2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00`
>
> or
>
> `2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00`

Therefore, in your case the `+0000` indicates a time offset of 0 from UTC.